# datarow not updating, no errors returned and ID is set

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable, datarow

on rowdeleting event im setting a field Deleted to 1, my code is as below, the ID is correctly set to 757 but the row does not get updated at all, there are no errors returned though, nothing it all :|

i also have a rowupdating event thats nearly identical to this, apart from it has all the fields in it and that works.

anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

```
protected void gvItems_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int intID = Convert.ToInt32(gvItems.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);


    DataRow drUpdate = (from d in dtEquipment.AsEnumerable()
                        where (int)d["ID"] == Convert.ToInt32(intID)
                        select d).SingleOrDefault();

    drUpdate["Deleted"] = "1";
    taEquipment.Update(drUpdate);
    reBind();
}

protected void reBind()
{
    gvItems.DataSource = dtEquipment;
    gvItems.DataBind();
    upTable.Update();
}
```

Heres some debug info ive got
the app breaks in debug mode under this function

```
function Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_endPostBack(error, executor, data) {
    if (this._request === executor.get_webRequest()) {
        this._processingRequest = false;
        this._additionalInput = null;
        this._request = null;
    }
    var handler = this._get_eventHandlerList().getHandler("endRequest");
    var errorHandled = false;
    if (handler) {
        var eventArgs = new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(error, data ? data.dataItems : {}, executor);
        handler(this, eventArgs);
        errorHandled = eventArgs.get_errorHandled();
    }
    if (error && !errorHandled) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

theres also a few of these in there too for columns not used in this page

```
PublicIP = '((dsData.tblEquipmentRow)(drUpdate)).PublicIP' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.StrongTypingException'
```

Comment: What's the type of `taEquipment`?

Comment: what does upTable.Update(); do?

Comment: its a table adapater, the update function does work on my onrowupdating dsDataTableAdapters.tblEquipmentTableAdapter taEquipment; upTable.Update() is an update panel that i update, Thanks

Comment: use `try{} catch(Exception ex){}` block for exact error..

Comment: Show the update command for taEquipment.

Comment: ive added some debug info ive obtained to the post